# Is there a way to export test parameters from SE37?

Tags: testing, abap, function-module

Is there a way to export the test variants of the test tool available in the transaction `SE37` and then import those variants into another system? I have not been able to find anything in the standard. Maybe there is a custom program which would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps table `EUFUNC` helps you.

See also [Table for test data saved in SE37 (Test data directory)](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1315227)
There are also some code examples. Maybe you can use it to build your own Export/Import function.